# Flask-Images does not work

Tags: python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I'm installed Flask-images for resizing some images. My code are like this:

```
<img src = '{{url_for('showimages', filename = market.thumbnail, width=100, height=100, mode='crop')}}'>
```

`showimages`:

```
@app.route('/image/user/<filename>')
def showthumbnail(filename):
return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

There are nothing happens and my Chrome devaloper tools said image's url like this:

```
<img src="/image/user/Untitled-1.png?width=100&amp;height=100&amp;mode=crop">
```

I know there is another way instead `url_for` - `resized_img_src()`.
I'm set `IMAGES_PATH= os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')`. 
However this configuration does not work and when I use resized_img_src(), only got broken image icon. I don't have a clue how can fix this.

+Is there any other easy ways to resizing uploaded images?

Answer (score 0):

Your template uses `showimages` whereas your Flask Python code shows `showthumnails`, I'll assume this is typo and code actually uses same as template.

Are these really the quote characters you are using in your template? You need to use the single and double quotes or escape the inner single ones. Try this instead:

```
<img src="{{url_for('showimages', filename=market.thumbnail, width=100, height=100, mode='crop')}}">
```