# Flask-Images is not working

Tags: python, flask

I installed Flask-Images to dynamically resize images according to the doco here: https://mikeboers.github.io/Flask-Images/

My code is like this:
Jinja

```
<img src="{{ resized_img_src(filename, width=200) }}"/>
```

And in views.py

```
@app.route("/uploads/<filename>", methods=["GET"])
def uploaded_file(filename):
  return send_from_directory(upload_path(), filename)
```

The images do not change size even though I can see that the modified url is being returned on dev tools:

```
  <img src="/uploads/69?w=200&amp;s=4tDuOKq1G1qURVty_6pYAxpG4jk">
```

I know something similar was asked here a while ago [Flask-Images does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259449/flask-images-does-not-work)
but the only answer there wasn't helpful.

I've been at this for 2 days now. If anyone has experience incorporating Flask-Images into their project, I'd appreciate any suggestions. Would people recommend using Flask-Resize instead?  https://github.com/jmagnusson/Flask-Resize.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: I can't see any image name (and extension) in the generated URL. Can you show more relevant code from you `views.py` file?

Comment: 69 was the image name above. I figured it though. It was a series of mistakes but the reason why the original (not resized) image was being displaying was because the route above was overwriting the route in flask-images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Issue

The problem with your current setup is that Flask-Images can't find the image file 69.

If you run your Flask application in debug mode, you would see the following 404 occur when you entered the URL with the image to be resized in it.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2015 17:09:50] "GET /imgsizer/uploads/beastie.png?w=200&s=3mNDiQA6kRKps70a7xBi0BywF2w HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

### Solution

For flask-images to be able to load the resource, we need to put it somewhere accessible, that would be the 'static' directory by default in Flask

The solution as stated above would be to either move the images into the static directory, you can also override the directory path in the app definition, or in a setting

```
app = Flask(static_folder='some_other_path_with_images')
app.config['STATIC_FOLDER'] = 'or_this_other_directory'
```

After fixing this, you can also check the app debug console and see the requests are going through just fine

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2015 17:18:47] "GET /imgsizer/beastie.png?v=VZfrJw&w=100&s=2_gsJZCVk-gvUm4VD-OD6ZuXjbY HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

### Source Code

Feel free to take a look at the model i set up to check this out, the solution for this problem can be found [here on github](https://github.com/mtnmts/stack_overflow_solutions/tree/master/31038826-flask-images-is-not-working).